# How to enable autoplay of video in sequences upon selection in a listview?

Tags: java, android, video

Hello guys can someone share with me on how am i going to code my viewvideo.java class such that it allow auto-play video function which automatically sequence the task of playing the selected video in a listview (from current position to the latest video recorded in sequence until the latest video in line has finished playing) which is something similar to the youtube auto-play function if you know what i mean?

Can someone help me pertaining to this problem i'm facing now i'm rather quite new to android/java programming and have been stuck on this problem for days... Sorry for my bad English above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all you need to do is call `videoView.setVideoPath(next_file_path)` and then call `videoView.start()`. If there are no more videos, then call `videoView.stopPlayback()`.

Here's something that might work:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (arg1 == 0) {
        Intent intentInfo = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, DialogBox.class);
        // Retrieve the path names of all videos from the top to the
        // selected item (inclusive).
        arrayPath = new String[selectedPosition+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= selectedPosition; ++i) {
            arrayPath[i] = videoItems.get(i).absolutePath;
        }
        VideoInfo info = videoItems.get(selectedPosition);
        intentInfo.putExtra("fileName", info.name);             
        intentInfo.putExtra("fileSize", info.size);
        intentInfo.putExtra("absolutePath", info.absolutePath);
        intentInfo.putExtra("arrayPath", arrayPath);

        startActivity(intentInfo);  
    }
    else
    {
        deleteFile();
    }
}
```

This passes the array of path names to your DialogBox activity (which you haven't posted). You should then be able to retrieve `arrayPath` and pass it on to the VideoView activity if the user selects to play all videos.

Comment: @Ted Hopp then how should i get (next_file_path) in the listview to get it to constantly find the new video in the listview entries?

Comment: Right now you put one video path in the `videoPath` extra. I suggest that you put the entire array of videos you want to play. (You can put a String array as easily as a single String into an intent extra.) That way the ViewVideo activity will know all the videos that need to be played. You can simply keep an index into which one is currently playing and go on to the next video file path when finished.

Comment: @Ted Hopp i have updated my answer but the part which you mean by "index" i really have no idea on how to implement into my codes?

Comment: Create two fields in your ViewVideo class: an integer `index` and a string array `filenames`. In `onCreate`, set `index=0` and `filenames` to the string array to the array of video path names retrieved from the intent (like you are doing now for `filename`). Replace references to `filename[??]` in `onCreate` with references to `filenames[index]`. Inside `onCompletion`, instead of calling `finish()` immediately, increment `index` and test whether `index < filenames.length`. If not, then finish; otherwise restart the video view with the next video.

Comment: @Ted Hopp but with what you are suggesting the viewvideo will play virtually everything in the directory file rather than playing the file selected in the listview through "position" to continue playing the much "newer" file in the timeline? Isn't what youtube does with autoplay?

Comment: @Ted Hopp shouldn't i be working on the position of the listview instead to get the next video path? If so how should i come about doing it?

Comment: @Vivian - make all the decisions about what video paths you want to play in your `OnClickListener, before you start the video play activity. Construct the array of path names that will go into the intent to include only those videos you want to play at that point, in the order in which they should be played. The job of the VideoView activity is simply to play them all in sequence, not make decisions about what to play.

Comment: @Ted Hopp but what are the decision i must make in the listview to make it get the video file selected and get the latest file path into an array?

Comment: You said you wanted to play "from current position to the latest video recorded in sequence until the latest video in line has finished playing". Just implement that logic. I'm not entirely sure what that means (whether it just means playing everything on display from the selected view to the end, or whether it involves scanning the directory for all files meeting some criterion). You need to implement code that does that. (It may be as simple as looking at the array of data the adapter is using to display the list.)

Comment: @Ted Hopp but the thing now is i don't really know how to continue with the logic to get all the required file path all the way to the end??

Comment: Isn't this simply the collection of file names on display in the list view (or a subset of them)?

Comment: @Ted Hopp sorry for confusing you with my horrible English (I mean i do not really know how to get the subset of string path starting from the selected position all the way to the top of the list?

Comment: @Ted Hopp sorry i got myself confused it should be the opposite of what i state above from selected to the bottom of the list of video... Sorry rather bad in what i want to say...

Comment: @Ted Hopp i have updated my code above but yet again it does not work the way i intended to store the file from the selected position to the end/bottom of the list? can you help me on this?

Comment: Your `videoItems` array already contains the information you need. Just start at `position` and retrieve from there to the end of the array.

Comment: @Ted Hopp sorry i'm rather lost?? "Just start at position and retrieve from there to the end of the array" ?? I actually wanted to get the .list to get the array "path" not the actual array file itself, sorry not knowing what i'm saying...

Comment: @Vivian - correct me if I'm wrong, but you have a ListActivity that is displaying the names of all the video files. The display is based on an ArrayList `videoItems` of VideoInfo objects, each of which contains the absoloute path of each video as well as its display name and other info. When the user selects an item from the list to play, you want to play that item and all items below it on the list. If that is correct, just retrieve the absolute path names from `videoItems` of those that you want played. (If I don't understand what you want, please explain.)

Comment: @Ted Hopp but according to the way i code my listview the latest video is placed at the top of the listview upon saving it but the older video is place at the bottom... That's why i was wondering if the user click "[2]" per say in the listview it should play "[1]" then follow by "[0]". That's why i have a weird logic of playing a reverse logic in the beginning...

Comment: @Vivian Okay, so retrieve the video path names in whatever order makes sense for your application.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Have posted this since yesterday but no one answered can you take a look and suggest me on how should i be creating this function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080654/how-to-create-youtube-start-stop-graphical-view-function

Comment: @Ted Hopp Sorry to trouble you again here but my code suddenly seems that it doesn't work with consistency as it should?? Sometime it worked fine running the autoplay but sometime it hit an dialog saying "video could not be played" only if i dismissed the dialog then the video could continue with autoplay and worst still the video sometime can't even play the index video and it jump to the next video?? What went wrong with my code above?? I have updated it my answer above...

Comment: @Ted Hopp i have added an logcat on the error. What wrong's with my coding? and if i'm not wrong it constantly sets that same file name in that videoPath despite me clicking the other item in the listview?

Comment: It looks like you are setting `index` to zero and then decrementing. If you want to go backwards in the array, initialize `index` to `filePath.length - 1`.