# Unable to close Progress Dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, dialog, progress

I want to create a progress dialog in android, keep it open for 2 seconds then close it.

Below is the code I have written:

```
package com.example.proressdialogtest;

import android.app.activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, 4);

        pg.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Searching...", false);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        pg.dismiss();
}
```

When I run the code on my device, the ProgressDialog is opened and then it stays open, it does not close after 2 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

---

As per the answers below. I have added the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods before and after the doInBackground method respectively.

Here is the code for the two methods.

```
ProgressDialog pd;

public void onPreExceute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Searching...", false);
}

public void onPostExecute() {
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

The problem still persists. The progress bar will not close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `sleep()` on the `UI Thread`. Don't do this. Use `runOnUiThread` or an `AsyncTask`

[Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I would use an `AsyncTask`. You will start the `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` then close it in `onPostExecute()`. It is a `UI` element so using it in `doInBackground()` will give you the error

**[This SO answer has a good example of using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713222/android-progress-dialog/7713264#7713264)**

Comment: I have an Async task in the program that I am using and it has one protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer...params) method. I have tried doing the above inside the doInBackground function but the same error occurred.

Comment: I tried integrating what was in that post into my code before I posted the question. But it didn't work. So I posted the question myself.

Comment: @aagarwal `onPostExecute()` gets called after `doInBackground()` finishes so you need to do some work in there like your `Thread.sleep()` call

Comment: @codeMagic As he isn't got the solution, I have undelete my answer and posted the one..

Comment: @Pragnani no problem. Its good for everyone to see different options

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ProgressDialog pg ;

      pg =  ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Searching...", false);

        Thread timer=new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                     pg.dismiss();
                }
            }

        };
        timer.start();
}
}
```

---

You are pausing the UI thread by calling

```
 Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Because Thread.sleep(x) will make the current thread sleep for x milli seconds

which is bad thing.

place

I don't know why

pg.dismiss() in finally block to make sure that progress dialog will be closed.

> And also your Code won't run because you have missed

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: I missed the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in the question, it was always there in the original code. I added this line finally { pg.dismiss(); } after the try/catch statement. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

following code will work for you,

```
 new AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>()
             {
                 ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

                 @Override
                 protected void onPreExecute()
                 {                         
                     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                             "Loading...");
                 }

                 @Override
                 protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
                 {
                     if (params == null)
                     {
                         return false;
                     }
                     try
                     {

                         Thread.sleep(2000);

                     }
                     catch (Exception e)
                     {

                         return false;
                     }

                     return true;
                 }

                 @Override
                 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
                 {
                     progressDialog.dismiss();                        

                 }
             }.execute();
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally frowned upon in SO :( Its good for members to know WHY the code will work so they can help themselves later on

Comment: This works perfectly however its the same as the code in codeMagic's example so I gave the check to him.